Is it possible to use GPU acceleration with an Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 155H laptop?
According to Intel documentation, this processor has an  Intel® Arc™ graphics GPU. Intel seems to indicate that Arc graphics is able to render cycles. However so far I have not been able to get any GPU acceleration.
My system is an ASUS Zenbook 14 UX3405MA with 16G of RAM and an Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 155H processor. It is a dual boot Windoes 11/ Kubuntu 24.04 system. I have tried installing Intel driver for both Windows and Ubuntu. It seems that ubuntu 24.04 is not supported by Intel (yet?) but also on windows I cannot get HW acceleration to work in blender.
Is there something I am missing or is my system simply not capable enough?

Please check the official minimum requirements for GPU acceleration https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware Only Intel dedicated GPUs are supported
